# Popup Script duplicating background script network activites - Chrome Extension

Tags: javascript, reactjs, google-chrome-extension

Im making a Chrome Extension using React and building using WebPack.  I've got 3 output files, background, content and popup.

In my injected content script, I have a function that does the following:

```
chrome.runtime.sendMessage({action: "getDesigns", name: $}, (response) => {
    if (response.error) throw(response.error);
    this.setState({
        designs: response.data.designs,
        fetching: false,
        selectedFile: null
    })
});
```

In my background script, I have a listener for that action, and when triggered it calls this function

```
function bgGetDesigns(req, sendResponse) {
    getDesigns({
        'per_page': 100,
        'name': req.name
    })
    .then((res) => {
        sendResponse({success: true, data: res});
    })
    .catch((e) => {
        sendResponse({success: false, error: e});
    });
}
```

What I have noticed though, is that if my popup script is open, when I call the sendMessage via the content script, the background script performs the network request (correct) however the popup script ALSO performs the network request (wrong)

Is this expected behavoir, or could this be something caused by the way webpack builds my bundle?

Comment: It can only mean your original background script was bundled in the compiled popup script so you need to fix your webpack config, I guess.

Comment: I need the background script to work with the popup script though, as I have to make the network requests via the background script and not the popup

Comment: The background script runs in a separate hidden background page so it makes little sense to include it in the popup script which runs in its own separate popup page.

Comment: Im using https://github.com/tshaddix/webext-redux this to use the background script as a redux store. For example, login via popup changes the state of the content script to show they're logged in immediately.    I wonder if this is causing the problem, as I am not directly including the background script in the popup bundle

Comment: Something is including it. My guess was it's your webpack config. Theoretically it's possible the authors of that library aren't aware that a background script runs in a separate background page, but I find it highly improbable, which leads to my guess that the mistake is somewhere in your code/config.

Comment: Ok, i think you've pointed me in the right direction.  My background.js file and content.js file are being included in the index.html file which is used for the popup.  Don't suppose you know how to exclude these from being added to the index.js file?

Comment: I haven't used webext-redux so I can only state the obvious: you need to find what's generating that html file and exclude both scripts as the popup shouldn't run them.